# Gemfile.lock generates BUNDLED WITH

Tags: rubygems, bundler, gemfile.lock

I have been googling around about this, seems I couldn't find a solution regarding this issue.
So here is a thing, I am currently working rails project with my colleague, it was working fine till she changed her laptop and re-setup her environment from scratch...

Whenever she changes something on the project, the `Gemfile.lock` always writes this at the end of the file:

```
BUNDLED WITH
1.10.0.rc
```

And every time she accidentally commits this `Gemfile.lock`, it gets really troublesome for other devs to work because it always gives a message that we need to commit/clash something because on our environment, it automatically remove it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either she has to downgrade her bundler or the rest of the team should upgrade their bundler, I would recommend the later of course

```
gem update bundler
```

Comment: Could my team just manually remove the `BUNDLED WITH` clause from the lock file instead?  What would be the pros and cons of that?

Comment: I think then the default bundler version will try to bundle and it's version which would replace the deleted line

Answer (score 0):

As of Bundler 2.3, Bundler will attempt to fetch the correct version of Bundler.

From https://bundler.io/blog/2022/01/23/bundler-v2-3.html

> In Bundler 2.3 and up (if you also have RubyGems 3.3 or higher), running bundle install will use the exact version from the BUNDLED WITH section of the lockfile. If that version is not installed before you run bundle install, the running version of Bundler will install the locked version, and then run your original command using the newly-installed locked version.

This would solve your problem, if you still have it. :-)